# MongoDB hidden node still receiving connections

Tags: database-design, mongodb, mongodb-3.6

I'm not sure if this question been asked before or if the following behavior of MongoDB is normal. Searching online output no results to this scenario.

Initially, we had a 3 node deployment, 1 Primary, 1 Secondary, and 1 Arbiter.

We wanted to add a ReadOnly replica to the cluster and remove the Arbiter node as well in the process. We added the following to the new node:

priority: 0
hidden: true
votes: 1
And removed the Arbiter in the same reconfiguration process so we always have 3 voting members and it leaves us with 1 Primary and 1 Secondary and 1 ReadOnly Node.

The complete process went through smoothly, however, we still end up seeing connections to the ReadOnly replica.

But when checking via db.currentOp(), no queries show up.

Based on the documentation on MongoDB website,

> Hidden members are part of a replica set but cannot become primary and
>   are invisible to client applications.

Is there a way to investigate why there are connections coming in? And if this is normal behavior?

**EDIT:** *(for further clarification)*

Assuming the following:

MongoDB A (Primary): 192.168.1.50

MongoDB B (Secondary): 192.168.1.51

MongoDB C (Hidden): 192.168.1.52

Client A: 192.168.1.60

Client B: 192.168.1.61

In the logs, we see the following:

```
2018-03-12T07:19:11.607+0000 I ACCESS   [conn119719] Successfully authenticated as principal SOMEUSER on SOMEDB
2018-03-12T07:19:11.607+0000 I NETWORK  [conn119719] end connection 192.168.1.60 (2 connections now open)
2018-03-12T07:19:17.087+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 192.168.1.60:47806 #119720 (3 connections now open)
2018-03-12T07:19:17.371+0000 I ACCESS   [conn119720] Successfully authenticated as principal SOMEUSER on SOMEDB
```

So if the other MongoDB instances were connecting, that would be fine, but my question is regarding why the clients are able to connect even when the hidden option is true and if that behavior is normal.

**EDIT2:**

To further clarify, the connection string does not include MongoDB C.

Connection String Format:

```
mongodb://mongodb-a.domain:27017,mongodb-b.domain:27017/?replicaSet=MyReplica
```

Hence, the client does not know MongoDB C exists and by theory, it should be hidden, but in our case it's not.

Comment: Outstanding questions from your duplicate post on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186717/mongodb-hidden-node-still-receiving-connections): What specific MongoDB driver and version are you using? Is the `SOMEUSER` noted in the log definitely a user from your application and not a manual connection? Are these connections always closed immediately after successful authentication? One more thought: would the hidden secondary happen to be on the same IP address and port as the former arbiter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal behavior. Those connections are from other mongod nodes, because every node "watches" every other node to see who is reachable. This because election must be started even in the situation where secondary node disappear from replica set.

Comment: Googling and collecting pieces of information from the network, it looks like that some of the drivers do "explore of replica set" and connects all nodes at replica set, even node is hidden... The driver just doesn't use that node as long as it is hidden. This because every node knows all other nodes and driver don't compare is there a difference between connection string and reported RS members. The driver just connects to every member and if a member says it's hidden right now, driver doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a hidden node is to provide specific `read-only` workloads, or have copies over your data. which are hidden from the application.Hidden nodes can also be set with a delay in their replication process. We call these delayed nodes.

The purpose of having `delayed nodes` is to allow resilience to application level corruption,without relying on cold backup files to recover from such an event. If we have a node delayed let's say one hour, and if your DBA accidentally drops a collection, we have one hour to recover all the data from the delayed node without needing to go back to back up file to recover to whatever the time that backup was created.

A `hidden member` maintains a copy of the `primary’s` data set but is invisible to client applications. Hidden members are good for workloads with different usage patterns from the other members in the `replica set`. Hidden members must always be **`priority 0 members`** and so cannot become primary. The `db.isMaster()` method does not display hidden members. Hidden members, however, may vote in `elections`. The most common use of `hidden` nodes is to support `delayed members`.

**Read Operations:** Clients will not distribute reads with the appropriate read preference to hidden members. As a result, these members receive no traffic other than basic replication. Use hidden members for dedicated tasks such as reporting and backups.

**`Delayed members`** should be hidden. In a sharded cluster, `mongos` do not interact with hidden members.

**Voting:** Hidden members may vote in replica set elections.If you stop a voting hidden member, ensure that the set has an active majority or the **`primary`** will step down.

As per MongoDB BOL Documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-a-hidden-replica-set-member/) The most common use of **hidden nodes** is to support `delayed members`. If you only need to prevent a member from becoming primary, configure a `priority 0 member`.

As MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/) for consideration requirements of `Delayed members`:

1. Must be [priority 0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-priority-0-member/#replica-set-secondary-only-members) members. Set the priority to 0 to prevent a
   delayed member from becoming primary.
2. Should be [hidden members](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/#replica-set-hidden-members).
       Always prevent applications from seeing and querying delayed
       members.
3. do vote in  [elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-election) for primary, if [members[n].votes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.members[n].votes) is
       set to 1.

> **Note:** A `priority 0` member is a member that cannot become *primary* and cannot trigger elections.

For further your ref [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/) and [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-a-hidden-replica-set-member/)

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, since that information is already known and hence trying to figure out why client connections are still coming to this instance

Comment: @Nikhil C.,The most common use of hidden nodes is to support delayed members. If you only need to prevent a member from becoming primary, configure a priority 0 member. As JJussi has already said that .